# linux used memory by unknown (not Slab)

Tags: linux

Memory occupied by unknown (VMware/CentOS)

Hello.
We have a server that has memory full used issue, but can not find what is eating memory.
Usage of memory has increased few days ago 40% -> neary 100% and stayed there since then.
We’d like to kill whatever eating memory.

**[Env]**

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

# arch
x86_64
```

**[status]**

```
#free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16334148   15682368     651780          0      10168     398956
-/+ buffers/cache:   15273244    1060904
Swap:      8388600     129948    8258652
```

Result of top  (some info are masked with ???)

```
#top -a   
top - 10:19:14 up 49 days, 11:13,  1 user,  load average: 1.05, 1.05, 1.10
Tasks: 145 total,   1 running, 143 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 11.1%us, 18.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 69.5%id,  0.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16334148k total, 15684824k used,   649324k free,     9988k buffers
Swap:  8388600k total,   129948k used,  8258652k free,   387824k cached
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                
17940 ???      20   0 7461m 6.5g 6364 S 16.6 41.5   1113:27 java                                                                                                                    
 4982 ???      20   0  941m 531m 5756 S  2.7  3.3 611:22.48 java                                                                                                                    
 3213 root      20   0 2057m 354m 2084 S 99.8  2.2 988:43.79 python                                                                                                                  
28270 ???      20   0  835m 157m 5464 S  0.0  1.0 106:48.55 java                                                                                                                    
 1648 root      20   0  197m  10m 1452 S  0.0  0.1  42:35.95 python                                                                                                                  
 1200 root      20   0  246m 7452  808 S  0.0  0.0   2:37.42 rsyslogd
```

Processes that are using memory (some info are masked with ???)

```
# ps aux --sort rss
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1200  0.0  0.0 251968  7452 ?        Sl   Sep12   2:37 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
root      1648  0.0  0.0 202268 10604 ?        Ss   Sep12  42:36 /usr/lib64/???
???     28270  0.1  0.9 855932 161092 ?       Sl   Sep14 106:49 /usr/java/???
root      3213 96.1  2.0 2107704 332932 ?      Ssl  Oct31 992:25 /usr/lib64/???
???      4982  0.8  3.3 964096 544328 ?       Sl   Sep12 611:25 /usr/java/???
???     17940  6.6 41.5 7649356 6781076 ?     Sl   Oct20 1113:49 /usr/java/???
```

Memory is almost 100% used, but with ps and top, we can only find processes that uses half of it.

We have checked slab cache, but it was not the cause.
Slab is only 90444 kB.
Nothing is found in syslog too.

Anyone has any idea how to detect what is eating memory?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Run `free -m` and see the difference. Column *available* shows real free memory.

And take a look at the https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 0):

we have restarted server and solved this case.